# Algorithm: Merge elements of n given sets into 2 empty sets A and B such that |A∩B| is least

Tags: algorithm

Example:
Given some sets S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 and 2 empty sets A and B.

- S1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
- S2 = [2,6]
- S3 = [7]
- S4 = [5]
- S5 = [1,2,3,4,5]

Case 1)

- A = S1∪S3∪S4 = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
- B = S2∪S5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
- |A∩B| = 5

Case 2)

- A = S1∪S5 = [1,2,3,4,5]
- B = S2∪S3∪S4 = [2,5,6,7]
- |A∩B| = 2

Here, Case 2 is the scenario with least no. of common elements between A and B.

Is there an algorithmic way to go about finding the combination with least common elements between A and B other than the naive approach of going through all combinations?

Comment: You write: S2∩S3∩S4 = [2,5,6,7] -- do you mean union rather than intersection? You write: "2 empty sets A and B" -- do you mean "2 non-empty sets A and B"? You write that Case 2 is minimal -- but B = S3, A = the other sets, results in a zero-sized intersection which is even more minimal -- is this another mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it allowed to put everything into set A? That way, you will get `|A∩B| = empty set`.

On your example, isn't combining:

- A = S1∩S2∩S4∩S5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
- B = S3 = [7]

Results in an even smaller |A∩B| which is, again, empty set?

Comment: Perhaps some constraints are omitted; the problem makes little sense in its current formulation.